# Index range of array doesn't allow you to iterate over a new line in bash

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, array

I'm working on a simple bash script that fixes a duplicate naming issue on a retropie.

The script itself grabs any name that is mentioned more than once in a gameslist.xml file, then stores those in an array for later use.

I end up looping over this array in indexes like so:

```
pi@retropie:~ $ for game in ${game_array[@]:0:10} ; do echo $game; done
```

which pulls the 1st to the 10th element (i.e. `${game_array[9]}`) 
however the output gets joined to one line:

```
pi@retropie:~ $ for game in ${game_array[@]:0:10} ; do echo $game; done
R.B.I. Baseball '94 World Series Baseball '95 Mega Games 1 Bill Walsh College Football T2: The Arcade Game Sonic &amp; Knuckles + Sonic the Hedgehog Sega Top Five Pyramid Magic Tecmo Super Baseball Super Chinese Tycoon
```

But if I loop over the entire array, it outputs on new lines as expected:

```
pi@retropie:~ $ for game in ${game_array[@]}; do echo $game; done | head -10
R.B.I. Baseball '94
World Series Baseball '95
Mega Games 1
Bill Walsh College Football
T2: The Arcade Game
Sonic &amp; Knuckles + Sonic the Hedgehog
Sega Top Five
Pyramid Magic
Tecmo Super Baseball
Super Chinese Tycoon
```

the field seperator has been set to new line with `IFS='$\n'` which is why the second one works, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it isn't with the first one?

here's the full test script for context:

```
#!/bin/bash

user_input=$1
while [ -z "$user_input" ]; do
        echo "please enter the name of the system you want to fix the game list for"
        echo "(as it is labelled in /home/pi/RetroPie/roms)"
        read -r user_input
done

ls "/home/pi/RetroPie/roms/$user_input" >/dev/null 2>&1

if  [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "this doesn't appear to be a system installed here. exiting."
        exit 1
fi

games_to_fix()
{
        IFS=$'\n'
        console=$1
        filepath="/opt/retropie/configs/all/emulationstation/gamelists/$console/gamelist.xml"
        game_array=($(fgrep "<name>" "$filepath" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk  '$1 > 1 {print $0}'| cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d "<" -f 1))
        number_to_fix=($(fgrep "<name>" "$filepath" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk  '$1 > 1 {print $1}'))
}

get_new_name()
{
        mYpath=$1
        new_name=$(echo $mYpath | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d "<" -f 1 | sed -e 's/\.\///g' | sed -e 's/\.7z//g')
}

games_to_fix $user_input

IFS=$'\n'
index=0
for i in ${number_to_fix[@]}; do
        loop=1
        for game in ${game_array[@]:$index:$i}; do
        #       for ind in $(eval echo {1..$i}); do
                line_number=$(fgrep -n "<name>$game</name>"  $filepath | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d : -f 1 | sed -e "${loop}q;d")
                path_line_number=$(expr $line_number - 1 )
                path=$(sed "${path_line_number}q;d" $filepath | cut -d : -f 2)
                get_new_name "$path"
                sed -i "${line_number}s/$game/$new_name/g" $filepath
                ((loop++))
        done
        index=$(expr index + $i);
done
```

Comment: I'm sceptical. What's in the array? `declare -p game_array`

Comment: Can you try to reduce your code to a *minimal* testable example that demonstrates the issue? as it stands, it's rather hard to understand exactly what you are asking. Are you sure the problem cannot be solved by proper quoting - for example `arr=("foo bar" "baz" "bam foo" "bar")` ; `for item in "${arr[@]:1:2}"; do echo "$item"; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In brief: *you should use quotes around array expansions* like that, unless you explicitly want field/word splitting. `"$@"` expands each positional parameter to a separate word, and similarly so does `"${a[@]}"`. By extension, that should work in the same way for `"${a[@]:0:2}"`.

---

That said, it still seems like an inconsistency in Bash, and what you used should work in your case (since there are no glob characters in the values, and field splitting is taken care of by `IFS` being set properly).

Taking the full array works:

```
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ a=("foo bar" "asdf ghjk")
$ printf "%s\n" ${a[@]}
foo bar
asdf ghjk
```

Slicing it doesn't work for an array, but works for `$@`:

```
$ printf "%s\n" ${a[@]:0:2}
foo bar asdf ghjk

$ set -- "aa bb" "cc dd"
$ printf "%s\n" ${@:1:2}
aa bb
cc dd
```

It does work in ksh and zsh, which sort of underlines Bash being inconsistent here <sub>(zsh of course would have its own syntax for the equivalent)</sub>:

```
$ ifs=$'\n' ksh -c 'IFS="$ifs"; a=("foo bar" "asdf ghjk"); printf "%s\n" ${a[@]:0:2}'
foo bar
asdf ghjk
$ ifs=$'\n' zsh -yc 'IFS="$ifs"; a=("foo bar" "asdf ghjk"); printf "%s\n" ${a[@]:0:2}'
foo bar
asdf ghjk
```

The quoted version works in Bash, too, and is better when you just want the values as-is, since you don't need to depend on `IFS`. The default `IFS` works fine here even though the array elements have spaces:

```
$ unset IFS                         # uses default of $' \t\n'
$ printf "%s\n" "${a[@]:0:2}"
foo bar
asdf ghjk
```

---

It looks as though the unquoted `${a[@]:0:2}` joins the elements with spaces, a bit like what happens in Bash in contexts where word-splitting doesn't happen (e.g. `str=${a[@]}`). And then it tries to split the result with `IFS`, as usual. E.g. here, it splits on the newline in the middle of the second array element:

```
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ a=("foo bar" $'new\nline' "asdf ghjk");
$ printf ":%s\n" ${a[@]:0:3}
:foo bar new
:line asdf ghjk
```

As said above, you really should use the quotes around array expansions in most cases, though still, one would assume `${a[@]:n:m}` would result in multiple words, just like `${a[@]}` does.

The behaviour here seems present in Bash `4.4.12(1)-release` and `5.0.0(1)-alpha`. I posted a bug report about it.

Comment: In `zsh`, you'd rather use `$a[1,2]` (or `"${(@)a[1,2]}"` or `"${a[@][1,2]}"` to preserve empty elements).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, doesn't `"${a[@]:1:2}"` work fine in zsh too? Of course zsh has its own way of doing that, I'm not arguing against that. Just using zsh as a point of comparison for something I see as a bug in Bash (even though the whole thing is something that probably shouldn't usually be used)

Comment: Yes, I'm just saying there are more idiomatic/native/sensible ways to do it in `zsh` (`${var:x:y}` was added much later in `zsh` and only for compatibility with ksh/bash as it had its own better way to do it before them). `bash` copied it from `ksh93`, you may want to check the status there.

Comment: Using an unquoted ${a[@]} causes the problem, and the problem is not a bug. For example: from man ksh *The meaning of $* and $@ is identical when not quoted*. Both unquoted expansions should become **one** string separated by spaces.

Comment: @Isaac, no, they shouldn't. Bash's reference puts it in plain text re `$*`: "($*) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion is not within double quotes, each positional parameter expands to a separate word. " and the text in POSIX is similar (for `$@`): "Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one, initially producing one field for each positional parameter that is set. When the expansion occurs in a context where field splitting will be performed, ... each of the non-empty fields shall be further split as described in Field Splitting."

Comment: @Isaac, links: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02 . I did mention in the answer that they should use quotes around that (since they don't seem to explicitly want word splitting). But it's still an inconsistency in Bash regarding how it handles `$@`, `${@:n:m}`, `${array[@]}` and `${array[@]:n:m}`.

Comment: @Isaac, of course, nothing defines exactly how the unquoted `${array[@]:n:m}` should act, unless ksh has it explicitly documented. It's not POSIX, and Bash's reference isn't explicit. But having it do something other than the equivalent of `${array[@]}`, other than acting just on part of the array, is just unexpectedly weird.

Comment: Well, it is explicit for arrays: *If the word is double-quoted, ${name[*]} expands to a single word with the value of each array member separated  by the first character of the IFS special variable, and ${name[@]} expands each element of name to a separate word.* The "$*" description is a documentation bug IMnshO.

Comment: @Isaac, yes, there are the magic words _"if double-quoted"_. The quoted case works fine, the inconsistency is with the unquoted one. And if you think Bash's manual is wrong regarding `$*`, POSIX also defines it to produce multiple fields, which are then further split as usual. The wording is exactly the same as what I quoted above for `$@`, see the link three comments up. (expanding without quotes is of course "a context where field splitting will be performed").

Comment: (FWIW, and just in case someone tests this and gets confused, at least some versions of `dash` and `busybox` get the unquoted `$*` wrong, try `sh -c 'IFS=; set -- "aa bb" "cc dd"; printf ":%s:\n" $*'` with different shells.)

Answer (score 2):

quote
**quote**

#### Quote

### Quote

## Quote!!

This works:

```
$ game_array=("foo bar" "baz" "bam foo" "bar")

$ for game in "${game_array[@]:0:10}" ; do echo "$game"; done
foo bar
baz
bam foo
bar
```